# Java: File reading/writing

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a file and replace all the dollar values to euros, for example if somewhere in the file there's $30.25, it should be converted to 26.84E. I managed to make it work somehow, but I don't know how to make it work if, for example, the text contains something like $30.25. (notice the dot in the end). I'm using the replace methods of string, but if I use replace(".",""), it obviously removes all dots there, so it won't work. Can you help me with any other way so this would work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "any dot that is surrounded by numbers"? Check out a tutorial on regex.

Comment: Is the file something that you create as a result of your program and later read in from? If it is, I think it would be best to identify what is causing the additional full stop and correct that, instead of checking for it later

Comment: so do you want https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the replace methods if you can isolate the occurrence you want to keep first, which could be done using [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

The below example uses a positive look-behind to split on the full stops. Definition of a positive look-behind from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/):

[image: Regex101 Positive lookbehind description]

---

```
private String replaceAllButFirstOccurrence(String text, String sequence){
    if(text.contains(sequence) && (text.indexOf(sequence) != text.lastIndexOf(sequence))){
        //There are at least 2 occurrences of the sequence
        String[] substrings = text.split("(?<=\\.)", 2); //Split in 2
        /*
            Input is now segmented in 2:
                [0] - The first sub string containing the first occurrence
                [1] - The second sub string containing the rest of the input that can be modified
         */
        return substrings[0] + substrings[1].replaceAll("\\.", "");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Sample:

```
$100 -> $100
$200.00 -> $200.00
$250.00. -> $250.00
$300.00.. -> $300.00
```